# Reshape JSON format

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm exhausted. I can't find solution and/or I simply can't do this by myself. I'm new to C# and I have no idea how to do this. I tried **several** methods and it took me all day.

How it looks now:

```
{
  "TimeStamp": "1406232939277",
  "Company": [
    {
      "Departments": [
        {
          "Name": "Customer Service",
          "Head": "John",
          "Teams": [
            {
              "Team": [
                {
                  "Person-1": "Mark",
                  "Person-2": "Tom",
                  "Person-3": "Bob"
                                },
                {
                  "Person-1": "Jean",
                  "Person-2": "Tyler",
                  "Person-3": "Beth"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
        {
          "Name": "IT Department",
          "Head": "Jones",
          "Teams": [
            {
              "Team": [
                {
                  "Person-1": "Stephanie",
                  "Person-2": "Ronald",
                  "Person-3": "Bruce"
                                },
                {
                  "Person-1": "Forest",
                  "Person-2": "Megan",
                  "Person-3": "Alex"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How it should look:

```
{
    "TimeStamp": "1406232939277",
    "Departments": [
        {
            "Name": "Customer Service",
            "Head": "John",
            "Teams": [
                {
                    "Person-1": "Mark",
                    "Person-2": "Tom",
                    "Person-3": "Bob"
                },
                {
                    "Person-1": "Jean",
                    "Person-2": "Tyler",
                    "Person-3": "Beth"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "IT Department",
            "Head": "Jones",
            "Teams": [
                {
                    "Person-1": "Stephanie",
                    "Person-2": "Ronald",
                    "Person-3": "Bruce"
                },
                {
                    "Person-1": "Forest",
                    "Person-2": "Megan",
                    "Person-3": "Alex"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I already deleted all the code and it was producing bad output anyway. I tried with `Json.NET` and `ServiceStack.Text` using their examples and google, but it's over my head.

Someone told me I should use the `CustomCreationConverter` and I tried, I really tried, but I couldn't do this and I wasted all day on that.

How can I reshape it?

**EDIT**:

I want to simplify the output by ignoring the `Company` element and moving the `Departments` in it's place. Also I want to the same thing with `Teams` and `Team` arrays, to ignore one of these, so there's just one array, not array in array.

I tried deserializing it and serializing it again, but it didn't let me 'omit' `Company`, I tried with `[XmlIgnore]` and others.

Comment: Are you expecting people to look at the two pieces of json and compare them, piece by piece? Please write up a comparison in accordance with what you want changed.

Comment: Did I correctly understand that you want to remove the `Company` entry ?

Comment: He also want the `"Team"` level gone, at least in the first occurance.

Comment: I am not expecting doing the work for me, I will provide all additional info you guys want, I just didn't know what else you want, because as I said I am new to programming. Let me edit my question

Comment: Is this a one-time job or something you need to do regularly? Can you change whatever it is that outputs the (clearly flawed) json file?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I get the XML Feed from another server and I deserialize it on my server. Then I serialize it again with JsonConvert to JSON String (and after I manage to reshape it to the desired output I want to store it on sql server).

Comment: I don't know how this is unclear to you guys. There's one question and explanation underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid string  manupulation you can

a)Deserialize your JSON string using JSON.NET

```
  OriginalClass m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OriginalClass>(json);
```

b)Create a class TransformedClass which has the fields you want to serialize

c)Copy the values from the original object to an instance of the TransformedClass

d)Serialize the new instance using JSON.NET

```
   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

*You can easily create the OriginalClass class using the function PasteSpecial in VisualStudio. Edit->Paste Special->Paste JSON AS Classes

Comment: I think I tried that before. Let me check again. Thanks for help.

Comment: It is very easy,if you have any problems just tell me

Comment: How do I copy values from the original object to an instance of the TransformedClass? Is there any method or Convert method for that?

Comment: There are more than 2 departments, I just put there these two. Can I use foreach or any other loop to repeat copying to all of nodes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58081/discussion-between-george-vovos-and-vixing).